# GIT: Não consigo mandar os meus arquivos para o GitHub

Tags: git, github

Não estou conseguindo **mandar meus arquivos para o GitHub**.
Estou seguindo os seguintes passos:

uso o

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'primeiro teste'
git config --global user.name nome
git config --global user.email email

git push urlDoGitHub
```

O que normalmente está acontecendo, é um erro:

```
warning: could not open directory 'SendTo/': Permission denied
On branch master

No commits yet

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

 ../../../../../.bash_history
        ../../../../../.cache/
        ../../../../../.eclipse/
        ../../../../../.gitconfig
        ../../../../../.p2/
        ../../../../../.tooling/
        ../../../../../.vscode/
        ../../../../../3D Objects/
        ../../../../../AppData/
        ../../../../../Contacts/
        ../../../../../Desktop/
        ../../../../
        ../../../../../Downloads/
        ../../../../../Evernote/
        ../../../../../Favorites/
        ../../../../../IntelGraphicsProfiles/
        ../../../../../Links/
        ../../../../../MicrosoftEdgeBackups/
        ../../../../../Music/
        ../../../../../OneDrive/
        ../../../../../Pictures/
        ../../../../../Saved Games/
        ../../../../../Searches/
        ../../../../../Videos/
        ../../../../../eclipse-workspace/
        ../../../../../eclipse/
        ../../../../../ntuser.dat.LOG1
        ../../../../../ntuser.dat.LOG2
        ../../../../../ntuser.ini

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Se eu uso o Git Add .
Erro:

git add .

```
fatal: Unable to create '/.git/index.lock': File exists.

Another git process seems to be running in this repository, e.g.
an editor opened by 'git commit'. Please make sure all processes
are terminated then try again. If it still fails, a git process
may have crashed in this repository earlier:
remove the file manually to continue.
```

Estou super confuso e preciso de ajuda.

OBS: Sou iniciante no GIT e já exclui o arquivo index.lock e não funcionou.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que eu entendi você tem que adicionar o repositorio remoto. Neste site ensina como faz https://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v2/Fundamentos-de-Git-Working-with-Remotes.
Teste com o comando **"git remote -v"**. Se não possui uma configuração é porque o repositório remoto não foi adicionado. Então você coloca **"git remote add nome(Geralmente Origin) URL"**. Agora você testa novamente o **"git remote -v"**, se aparecer, esta tudo certo. Agora você pode dar o **"git push nome(Geralmente o origin) master"** para enviar os arquivos para o github.

Agora se o problema for outro fala. De um git status para ter maior certesa e posta ai.

Answer (score 0):

**Problema resolvido!**

O problema era que o VS Code não estava sincronizado com o diretório que o GIT apontava, tive que ir na aba files do VS e abrir a pasta em que o projeto estava salvo, dai em diante o meu git status passou a funcionar como deveria e eu consegui clonar e enviar os arquivos para o GitHub. Obrigado pelo suporte!

Answer (score -1):

Can try this one

```
git remote add <URL>
git add.
git push <remote name> <branch name>
```